# merge xml element attribute

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I have an input xml

```
<IndexCatalogueRecord SeriesNumber="1" SeriesVolume="3" SeriesPage="594">
<IndexCatalogueID>10305941390</IndexCatalogueID>
<GeneralNote>[Shelved in: B.58]</GeneralNote>
<GeneralNote>[Shelved in: B.458]</GeneralNote>
<GeneralNote>[Shelved in: B.20]</GeneralNote>
<Language>fr</Language>
</IndexCatalogueRecord>
```

and I need a solution to combine the GeneralNote element attributes seperate by a comma delimiter so that it becomes

```
<IndexCatalogueRecord SeriesNumber="1" SeriesVolume="3" SeriesPage="594">
<IndexCatalogueID>10305941390</IndexCatalogueID>
<GeneralNote>[Shelved in: B.58, B.458, B.20]</GeneralNote>
<Language>fr</Language>
</IndexCatalogueRecord>
```

My approach was have xmlstarlet query the element for attribute value and then pipe that to process with grep or awk. I can easily grab the value of the attribute from GeneralNote using xmlstarlet

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//GeneralNote" -v . -n test.xml
```

but when I tried to pipe the console output to grep to have it strip the matching string "[Shelved in:" and "]" I am having some trouble, please let me know if there's an more elegant solution. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is using two nested `xmlstarlet` commands
(pay attenttion to the two occurrences of the filename in the expression):

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/IndexCatalogueRecord/GeneralNote[1]" \
  -v "$(xmlstarlet sel -t -o "[Shelved in: " -m "/IndexCatalogueRecord/GeneralNote" \
  -v "substring-after(substring-before(.,']'),'[Shelved in: ')" \
  --if 'position() != last()' -o ', ' -b -b -o "]" input.xml)" \
  -d "/IndexCatalogueRecord/GeneralNote[position() > 1]" input.xml
```

The inner `xmlstarlet` command creates the final value from *all* `GeneralNote` elements and the outer command updates the first `GeneralNote` element and deletes the other. In xmlstarlet `ed` is the edit value mode and `sel` is the select value mode.

- `-u` - means update value
- `-v` - retrieves a value by XPath
- `-m` - iterates over all nodes matching an XPath expression
- `-o` - outputs a static string
- `-b` - ends an iteration or an if-clause
- `-d` - deletes all nodes matching the XPath

If you want to modify the XML *in-place*, add an `-L` option right after the `xmlstarlet ed`.